# How to open a browser window at 25% of its default size?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to launch a window at 25% of its default device browser window size.

I tried the one below, and it worked. But its limitation is it can only take pixel as inputs, not the relative % as the inputs. So it will not be scalable across devices.

```
window.resizeTo(width, height);
```

Any suggestions please?

**Update**:
How do I force this window to open in a new browser and with the address bar hidden?

I am trying to launch a chat window so it should always open in a new and reduced window without any tools  except close, min/max buttons on browser.

Comment: Have a look at [`window.innerHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerHeight) and see if that helps. Hint: You will need to do some math :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var h = window.innerHeight * .25;
var w = window.innerWidth * .25;
window.resizeTo(w,h);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var width = $( window ).width()/4;
    var height = $( window ).height()/4;
    var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width="+width+"px,height="+height+"px");
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: jquery is not needed at all for this - why include it?

Comment: i have used jquery for get window height and width and thats why i have added that.

Comment: Appreciate you responding to this. This actually opens a new window since you have used window.open(), but I am looking at resizing the base window when someone clicks hit the url.

Answer (score -1):

```
var specs = "width="+screen.width/4+",height="+screen.height/4;
window.open("http://www.w3schools.com","sample",specs)
```

Yeah you are right, it will not take percentages or anything. Only pixels are allowed. Use `screen` object to get height and width.

Comment: OP wants _window browser size_ not _screen size_.

Comment: he said 25% of its default device browser window

Comment: Yer, I read that too. It means "browsers window size", not "screen size".

Comment: by default, it won't be screen width?

Comment: No, it is not. I have two different browser open now, both are not at the screen width and height.

Comment: but the default one should have same.. user could have resized it, default would have been same. let OP decide what he wants..